# Fire a method when the URL is clicked - beginner

Tags: grails, groovy

I will be sending an user with the following URL

Example:  http://ipaddress.com/MyApp/user/verify?val=676687jhjhjdfhjdhfjdfhemail=email@gmail.com

When the user clicks on this, I need a method call `verify()` in the `UserController` to get fired up and it should get assigned to a variable called `val` and `email`.

I will then cross check with the database and check if the `val` is equal to the `email`

How can I do this. I know how to send the URL to the user but I am not sure how to write the method that will be fired after the URL is clicked.

```
def verify (String val, String email) {

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Few things to note:

-- When you are sending the URL to the user then make sure the URL is valid, i.e., it should be like: `http://example.com/user/verify?...` and not like: `/user/verify?...`. Send URL like

```
<g:link controller="user" action="verify" params="[val:'val', email: 'email']" absolute="true">Click Here</g:link>
```

or

```
<g:link controller="user" action="verify" params="[val:'val', email: 'email']" base="${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}">Click Here</g:link>
```

-- If you are using spring security and your controller is secured and you want user hit this action without login then make is available to all the users using `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` like

```
@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')
def verify (String val, String email) {
    ...
}
```

-- Your action is fine. It should be under `UserController`

-- The URL you pasted in the question is missing `&`. To get the `val` and `email` in your action, your URL should be like:

```
 http://ipaddress.com/MyApp/user/verify?val=676687jhjhjdfhjdhfjdfh&email=email@gmail.com
```

Comment: The values `${value}` in this results as a string. how can i pass the actual value carried by that attribute ? . `params="[val:'${value}', email: '${attr}']"`

Comment: like: `params="[val: value, email: attr]"`

Comment: "make sure the URL is valid, i.e., it should be full address with host name.".  The URL does not have to have the host name to be valid.  Relative URLs can be valid and are very common.

Comment: Thanks @JeffScottBrown, I have updated my answer. If any other modification required then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this...

```
// grails-app/controllers/com/demo/UserController.groovy
package com.demo

class UserController {
    def verify(String val, String email) {
        // do whatever you need to do here...
    }
}
```

Then in a GSP you can create a link to that with something like this:

```
<g:link action="verify" controller="user" params="[val:'someValueForVal', email: 'someValueForEmail']">Click Here</g:link>
```

If your controller is `UserController` then the controller name in the tag should be `user`.

**EDIT:**

Based on a question in the comment below I now wonder if what you really have in mind is using command objects so your controller action can accept some arbitrary object type, as shown below:

```
// grails-app/controllers/com/demo/UserController.groovy
package com.demo

class UserController {
    def verify(SomeClass someClass) {
        // do whatever you need to do here...
        // someClass.val will be equal to params.val
        // someClass.email will be equal to params.email
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    String val
    String email
}
```

More information about using command objects in Grails may be found at http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects.

Comment: The values `${value}` in this results as a string. how can i pass the actual value carried by that attribute ? . `params="[val:'${value}', email: '${attr}']"`

Comment: What you have there but without the single quotes around `${value}` and `${attr}` will work but the fact that you are asking about that suggests that you may be confused.  You can't pass any arbitrary object as a request parameter.  HTTP won't allow it.  The `g:link` tag is going to convert the value to a String when generating the URL.  You can map those String request parameters to arbitrary objects when you receive the request, but the `g:link` tag doesn't really have anything to do with that.